# How to fix code and make post request from react to laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, data-structures

We have to send data to backend. Backend gives us structure which it can recieve data. This is code in which recieves data with PHP laravel:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request, UploadImageService $uploadImageService){
       // dd($request->all());
        $product = Product::create($request->validated());

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $uploadImageService->upload($product, 'image', 'product_images', true, false);
        }
     else{
        return response()->json(['image must be file'],422);
     }
        if ($request->has('color_image')) {
            $data=[];
            foreach ($request->color_image as $key => $images) {
                $data[]=$images;
              
              
            }
            /* dd($data); */
            foreach ($data as $image) {
             /*    dd($image); */
                $mediaItem = $product->addMedia($image)->toMediaCollection('products_images');
                $mediaItem->setCustomProperty('color_id', $key);
                
                $mediaItem->save();
            }
        }
    /*     dd('gfdd'); */
        if ($request->filled('sizes')) {
            $product->sizes()->sync($request->sizes);
        }

        if ($request->filled('categories')) {
            $product->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        }

        if ($request->filled('genders')) {
            $product->genders()->sync($request->genders);
        }
      
        if ($request->filled('colors')) {
            $colors = $request->colors;
          

            if ($product->colors()->count() > 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors['color_id']); $i++) {
                    $product->colors()->attach($colors['color_id'][$i], [ 'stock' => $colors['stock'][$i]]);
              
                }
              

            } else {
            
                $product->colors()->detach();
               // dd(count($colors['color_id']));
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors['color_id']); $i++) {
                    $product->colors()->attach($colors['color_id'][$i], [ 'stock' => $colors['stock'][$i]]);
                }
            }


        }
     
        if ($request->filled('materials')) {
            $product->materials()->sync($request->materials);
        }
    

        return $this->successResponse($product);
    }
```

Below will be code in react where we post data. When we console.log data, it gives exacly the structure which backend want from us. In postman everything works fine but when we click send button, it returns "500 internal server error" and backend cannot recieve data.

```
const colors = { 'color_id[]': [...arrColorId], stock: [...arrColorStock] };
req.append("colors", JSON.stringify(colors));
dispatch(saveNewProduct(req));
```

Here is what backend developer told me that data should be:

```
array:2 [ // app/Http/Controllers/Back/ProductController.php:60
  "color_id" => array:1 [
    0 => "1"
  ]
  "stock" => "21"
]
```

and our code is exact like this when we log it.

Comment: > `when we click send button, it returns "500 internal server error"` <<<=== great! That means Laravel has logged the error in its error log. Find the error and copy/paste entire stacktrace in your original question

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is while you create the product with validated array which contains the image object which means the database will gives you an error because you are trying to insert unsupported data type to database.
Try to upload the image first then replace its value in validated array with the uploaded path like so:

```
$data = $request->validated();
$path = upload($request->file('profile_image'));
$data['profile_image']=$path;
```

If this doesn't work then try to paste the stack trace of the exception in laravel log

Comment: Replace the upload function with your function